# How to get vm public ip with azure sdk?

Tags: c#, azure

Im using the `Microsoft.Azure.Compute.Fluent` sdk to list all my VMs and it´s working fine, except i cant get the public ip address:

```
    IVirtualMachines _client = azure.VirtualMachines; 
    var list = await _client.ListAsync();

    foreach (var instance in list)
    {
        var name = instance.Name;
        var ip = instance.GetPrimaryPublicIPAddress().IPAddress;
        //ip = null here;
    }
```

Well I Tried other stuff but always getting the public ip as null.

How can I retrieve the Public IP correctly?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474171/how-to-get-public-ip-of-azure-vm-using-azure-sdk/43503511#43503511) is helpful.

Comment: Does the answer below work for you? If you have more question, please let me know. If it works for you, could you please mark it as answer? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct me if I misunderstand you: I can't find the sdk **Microsoft.Azure.Compute.Fluent**(screenshot as below):

[image]

So I use this sdk **Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent** instead(The [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/csharp#install-the-package) also uses it). And the ip can be fetched at my side, code as blow:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace myVMDotnetProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetVMInfo();

            Console.WriteLine("okok");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        static async Task  GetVMInfo()
        {
            var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User));

            var azure = Azure
                .Configure()
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                .Authenticate(credentials)
                .WithDefaultSubscription();

            IVirtualMachines _client = azure.VirtualMachines;
            var list = await _client.ListAsync();

            foreach (var instance in list)
            {
                var name = instance.Name;
                var ip = instance.GetPrimaryPublicIPAddress().IPAddress;
                Console.WriteLine("name: " + name + ", ip: " + ip);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Test result as below:

[image]